# How to align similar math expressions listed

Tags: latex, tex, typesetting

I am trying to align the 4 equations in this section. The problem is, I can't use the `\begin{align}` environment since they are each listed after blocks of text. Ideally all the equations would end up aligned. I have played with `\hspace` and `\hfill` but don't think they are the best solutions to this. What would be the proper and most robust approach to this?

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
\subsection*{Cumulative distributions}
Cumulative frequency distribution: $F(d) = \int_{0}^{d} f(x) dx$ \\
Cumulative number distribution: $N(d) = \int_{0}^{d} n(x) dx$ \\
Cumulative mass distribution: $M(d) = \int_{0}^{d} m(x) dx$ \\
Cumulative number distribution: $V(d) = \int_{0}^{d} v(x) dx$ \\
```

Comment: Could you include the text within the math tags and then use align?

Comment: @metropolis wouldn't that italicize all text as it interprets them as variables and such?

Comment: Yeah, it'd certainly change the appearance. You can use \text{} or \textnormal{} to get back to the current or document default fonts, respectively.

Comment: Ok that's possible too, but then the problem is that the text is going to be shifted towards the right depending on the alignments of the equations when I would prefer the text all to stay left justified

Comment: You should be able to align the text and the equations. Like this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56627/multiple-alignment

Comment: OK this looks like good stuff. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number ways of achieving this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox,mathtools}

\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{d}x}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\subsection{Cumulative distributions}
Cumulative frequency distribution: $F(d) = \int_0^d f(x) \dx$ \\
Cumulative number distribution: $N(d) = \int_0^d n(x) \dx$ \\
Cumulative mass distribution: $M(d) = \int_0^d m(x) \dx$ \\
Cumulative number distribution: $V(d) = \int_0^d v(x) \dx$

\subsection{Cumulative distributions}
Cumulative frequency distribution:\ $\phantom{M(d)}\mathllap{F(d)} = \int_0^d f(x) \dx$ \\
\rlap{Cumulative number distribution:}%
\phantom{Cumulative frequency distribution:}\ $\phantom{M(d)}\mathllap{N(d)} = \int_0^d n(x) \dx$ \\
\rlap{Cumulative mass distribution:}%
\phantom{Cumulative frequency distribution:}\ $M(d) = \int_0^d m(x) \dx$ \\
\rlap{Cumulative number distribution:}%
\phantom{Cumulative frequency distribution:}\ $\phantom{M(d)}\mathllap{V(d)} = \int_0^d v(x) \dx$

\subsection{Cumulative distributions}
\eqmakebox[cfd][l]{Cumulative frequency distribution:} $\eqmakebox[Md][r]{$F(d)$} = \int_0^d f(x) \dx$ \\
\eqmakebox[cfd][l]{Cumulative number distribution:} $\eqmakebox[Md][r]{$N(d)$} = \int_0^d n(x) \dx$ \\
\eqmakebox[cfd][l]{Cumulative mass distribution:} $\eqmakebox[Md][r]{$M(d)$} = \int_0^d m(x) \dx$ \\
\eqmakebox[cfd][l]{Cumulative number distribution:} $\eqmakebox[Md][r]{$V(d)$} = \int_0^d v(x) \dx$

\subsection{Cumulative distributions}
%\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{\ } r @{} l @{}}
  Cumulative frequency distribution: & $F(d) = {}$ & $\int_0^d f(x) \dx$ \\
  Cumulative number distribution:    & $N(d) = {}$ & $\int_0^d n(x) \dx$ \\
  Cumulative mass distribution:      & $M(d) = {}$ & $\int_0^d m(x) \dx$ \\
  Cumulative number distribution:    & $V(d) = {}$ & $\int_0^d v(x) \dx$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

1. The default display
2. Using some box manipulation, setting overlapping content and `\phantom`s.
3. Using [`eqparbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) to set content with similar `<tag>`s in boxes of the same width. Alignments can also be specified.
4. Using a `tabular` to align content horizontally. Drawback is that the structure cannot be broken across the page like the other options.

Comment: This is really great! Thanks for taking time to outline different methods. I'm wondering if you also know how I might add the display feature to these equations, so that they show with larger integrals and bigger line spaces. Is that possible?

Comment: @teepee: Add `\displaystyle` within `$`...`$`.